# How to get more random elements from an array, than the array has?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code to get 3 random values from my array:

```
$maps_clean = array_filter($find_league_maps);
$random_maps = array_rand($maps_clean,3);

$league_match_maps = ",".$maps_clean[1].",".$maps_clean[2].",".$maps_clean[3].",";
```

This works as long as the array has at least 3 values. Now I want to modify my code so that when I want more random values than I have in my array, it just gets new ones out of the array again. Yes, this means I can have some values more than once.

How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *iterate back over and add another value*? Do you mean use a value just twice? Or do you mean a default value? ...?

Comment: Just to note: `array_rand()` returns an array full of random keys. You just access the array by its own and don't use `$random_maps` at all.

Comment: @Yes you want to fill the third, but with what? A default value? A value from the array, which then is just 2 times in the output? With what do you want to fill the third one?

Comment: [A code snippet says more than a thousand words](https://3v4l.org/aLl4i)

Comment: My question still stands: If you have an array such as `[5, 10]` and you want 3 random values from it. With what do you want to fill the 3rd one? With a default value such as 100? Or with a value again out of the array, so you end up with `[5, 10, 5 or 10]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple while loop and [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array inside of it, then get as many random elements as you need with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Now if you want more random values than you have array elements, it simple takes the entire array, goes into the next iteration and takes the rest which it needs from the new shuffled array.

Code

```
<?php

    $arr = [1,2,3,4];


    $random = 5;
    $result = [];

    while(count($result) != $random){
        shuffle($arr);
        $result = array_merge($result, array_slice($arr, 0, $random - count($result))); 
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Since the OP seems to be using this for creating pairs, I would suggest pulling out the first two entries from the shuffled array to avoid having an entry paired with itself.

Comment: @Anthony I don't quite get what you mean with pairs? And I am pulling the first two entries from the shuffled array.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the elements having the same keys of an array fill with values with your `$maps_clean`.

```
$maps_clean = array_replace(array_fill(1, 3, null), array_filter($find_league_maps));
```

Here `array_fill` returns:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  NULL
}
```

and its elements are replaced by the elements returned by `array_filter($find_league_maps)` that have the same keys.

Comment: Love this answer! I personally would extract the arguments to `array_replace` into variables for readability, but that `array_fill` function is a new one for me

Comment: You want to check OP's clarified question. OP wants to fill up the missing values with values from the array again.

Answer (score 0):

The array key is start from 0 by default so, try with

```
 $league_match_maps = ",".$maps_clean[0].",".$maps_clean[1].",".$maps_clean[2].",";
```

also what is the output of `count($maps_clean)`?

Comment: You probably also want to look at this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464573/php-random-array-and-fill-array-if-less-than-the-amount?noredirect=1#comment60542145_36464573